# Previous masterrow is still selected when being collapsing by another masterrow kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that is using detailInit, when I open a masterrow its fine, when I open another masterrow, the previous masterrow collapses as it should, however it still has a selected state. This is the first time that I have ran into this issue.

Every other time I have created these types of grids, the previous masterrow never retains its selected state, and there really is no difference between this grid and others that I have written.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadSubmitToFactoryRooms(RoomsList());
});

function RoomsList() {
  let rooms = [{
      RoomID: 1,
      RoomName: "Room A",
      Areas: [{
        AreaID: 1,
        AreaName: "Area 1"
      }, {
        AreaID: 5,
        AreaName: "Area 5"
      }]
    },
    {
      RoomID: 2,
      RoomName: "Room B",
      Areas: [{
        AreaID: 2,
        AreaName: "Area 2"
      }, {
        AreaID: 6,
        AreaName: "Area 6"
      }]
    },
    {
      RoomID: 3,
      RoomName: "Room C",
      Areas: [{
        AreaID: 3,
        AreaName: "Area 3"
      }, {
        AreaID: 7,
        AreaName: "Area 7"
      }]
    },
    {
      RoomID: 4,
      RoomName: "Room D",
      Areas: [{
        AreaID: 4,
        AreaName: "Area 4"
      }, {
        AreaID: 8,
        AreaName: "Area 8"
      }]
    }
  ];
  return rooms;
}

function LoadSubmitToFactoryRooms(roomList) {
  $("#SubmitToFactoryRoomsListGrid").empty();
  $("#SubmitToFactoryRoomsListGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: roomList,
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            RoomID: {
              nullable: false,
              editable: false
            },
            RoomName: {
              nullable: false,
              editable: false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    toolbar: [{
        name: "SelectAllRooms",
        template: "<button id='btnSelectAllRooms' type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-small pull-left' onclick=''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-check'></span> Select All Rooms</button>"
      },
      {
        name: "SelectNoRooms",
        template: "<button type='button' id='btnSelectNoRooms' class='btn btn-warning btn-small pull-right' onclick=''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Select No Rooms</button>"
      }
    ],
    columns: [{
        title: '',
        template: "<center><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='#=RoomID #'/></center>",
        width: "30px"
      },
      {
        field: "RoomID",
        title: "RoomID",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        field: "RoomName",
        title: "Room"
      }
    ],
    height: "100%",
    detailInit: STFRoomAreas,
    detailExpand: function(e) {
      roomAreasGrid = e.sender;
      roomAreasGrid.select(e.detailRow.prev());
      roomAreasGrid.collapseRow(roomAreasGrid.tbody.find('> tr.k-master-row').not(e.masterRow));
    }
  });
}

function STFRoomAreas(e) {
  $("<div class='eagClass' id='" + e.data.AreaID + "' />").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: false,
    columns: [{
        title: "AreaID",
        field: "AreaID",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='#=AreaID #' />",
        width: "2px"
        //field: "checkable",
        //title: "checkable",
        //template: kendo.template(" <input type='checkbox' #= checkable ? 'checked' : '' # />  "),
        //width: "10px"
      }, {
        field: "AreaName",
        title: "Area Name",
        width: "20px",
        template: "<div >#=AreaName #</div>"
      }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: e.data.Areas,
      schema: {
        id: "AreaID",
        model: {
          fields: {
            AreaID: {
              nullable: true
            },
            AreaName: {
              validation: {
                required: true,
                maxLength: function(input) {
                  if (input.val().length < 1) {
                    input.attr("data-minlength-msg", "Min length is 1 character");
                    return false;
                  }
                  return true;
                }
              },
              nullable: false,
              editable: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    dataBound: function(w) {},
    change: function(e) {}
  });
}
```

```css
#SubmitToFactoryRoomsListWrapper {
  height: 350px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#SubmitToFactoryRoomsListGrid .k-grid-toolbar {
  padding-right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="SubmitToFactoryRoomsListWrapper">
  <div id="SubmitToFactoryRoomsListGrid">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing in the grid was one line of code and that was

```
selectable: "row"
```

after adding that in there then the previous masterrow was not staying selected anymore